# How do I use left join and Having with multiple filters?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in my database.

Table 1 has a list of indicators with the name `indicators`

The `indicators` table has columns like `indi_id` as primary key, `indi_name`, `target` and `objective`

and table 2 has a list of reported indicators called `report_indicators`  with columns like `report_indi` a foreign key from indicators table, `achieved_number`, `report_date` and `id`.

Ideally, I want a query that will get all the records from indicators with or without matching values from `report_indicators` the only matching records from `report_indicators` grouped by objective having a filter condition

- A. records from `report_indicators` with `achieved_number` below 5.
- B. records with `achieved_number` above 150,
- C. records with `achieved_number` above 250.

I tried the following query but I can’t figure out how to write it with HAVING filters

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(report_indicators.achieved_number) as achieved_count,  
    COUNT(indicators.target) as number_count, 
    indicators.objective 
FROM 
    indicators 
LEFT JOIN 
    report_indicators on report_indicators.report_indi_id = indicators.indi_id 
GROUP BY 
    objective
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 1):

You may place the `having` clause at the end eg for scenario A.

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(report_indicators.achieved_number) as achieved_count, 
    COUNT(indicators.target) as number_count, 
    indicators.objective 
FROM 
    indicators 
LEFT JOIN 
    report_indicators on report_indicators.report_indi_id = indicators.indi_id 
GROUP BY 
    objective
HAVING
    COUNT(report_indicators.achieved_number) < 5
```

Comment: Thanks ggordon, I get an SQL error using this solution.  can I simply ask how to get all records from indicators, and add more than one filter in having clause

Comment: What error did you receive, I had only added a solution based on your previous query, if you share the schema and some sample data I could assist you with the debugging. You may use AND or OR to add multiple filters in the HAVING clause. Please update your question with some sample data and expected results so that I can update this answer.

Comment: so i have this true sql . SELECT report_on_indicators.achieved_target,COUNT(report_on_indicators.achieved_target) as achieved_count, SUM(report_on_indicators.achieved_target) as achieved_sum, indicators.indi_spillar_name, COUNT(indicators.indi_targets) as number_count,SUM(indicators.indi_targets) as number_sum FROM indicators LEFT JOIN report_on_indicators on report_on_indicators.reporting_indi_id = indicators.indi_no GROUP BY indi_spillar_name

Comment: so if i add your solution to the post like SELECT report_on_indicators.achieved_target,COUNT(report_on_indicators.achieved_target) as achieved_count, SUM(report_on_indicators.achieved_target) as achieved_sum, indicators.indi_spillar_name, COUNT(indicators.indi_targets) as number_count,SUM(indicators.indi_targets) as number_sum FROM indicators LEFT JOIN report_on_indicators on report_on_indicators.reporting_indi_id = indicators.indi_no GROUP BY indi_spillar_name  HAVING COUNT(report_indicators.achieved_target) <1600

Comment: Error is #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(report_indicators.achieved_target) <1600 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: I recreated your schema in a fiddle with the answer I provided, there were no errors, see working [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kSou9qWm2e2PhfszxZYEno/0). However, when I replicated with your new sql shared in the comments [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2jTbPPeb8qsj9ZHHGmkujw/0) it states that you should not have `SELECT report_on_indicators.achieved_target,` but `SELECT COUNT(report_on_indicators.achiev...` because `report_on_indicators.achieved_target` is not in the group by list. When removed see [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2jTbPPeb8qsj9ZHHGmkujw/1) There are no errors.